# how to construct a method as like as "concat()"

Tags: java, concatenation

```
 i have coded....

public class mystring{
 public String concaT(String s1,String s2){
    s1=s1+s2;
    return s1;
  }
 public static void main(String[] args){
    String s="stack at";
    mystring obj=new mystring();
    System.out.println(s.concaT("concat"));
  }
}
```

the thing is, the main method is taking input concaT(s,"concat"), but i want to use s.concaT("concat"). how to make it possible???

Comment: The concaT method you created is on the MyString class and not in java.lang.String

Answer (score 1):

`String` class is `final` defined in library, you can not make sub class it so you can not add any new method to it.

`String#concat(java.lang.String)` is already available in library use that.

```
s.concat("concat")
```

Answer (score 1):

`s` is and object of type String. To do `s.concat(String)` you have to implements this method into `String.class` but this isnt possible because String is a final class that cant be extended otherwise you can creat a subclass of String and implement the method there. Why you did not want to use the `String.concat(String)` which is still implemented in String class?

Answer (score 0):

Make it static:

```
public class mystring{
   public static String concaT(String s1,String s2){
      s1=s1+s2;
      return s1;
   }
   public static void main(String[] args){
      String s="stack at";
      mystring obj=new mystring();
      System.out.println(concaT(s, "concat"));
   }
}
```

If you want to use it outside the class `mystring` you must either call it by `mystring.concat ("first", "second")` or insert an `import static mystring.concaT` at the beginning of the file to make Java know that you mean that method:

```
import static mystring.concaT;

// ...

class OtherClass {
   public void someMethod () {
      String s = concaT ("first", "second");
   }
}
```